# Blender 2.8: object pivot + pixel align + object part grouping (newbie)

Tags: blender

I have started learning Blender 2.8 as of May-25.  Almost 10 years ago, I was using 3dmax v7 but only as a hobby.  I want to start doing 3ding again as hobby but got no money to have something that is up to date. So I chose Blender.

Now I have a few questions. I will surely have more questions later.  I am still thinking in terms of 3dmax ways.

- How do I recenter the object pivot if I accidentally displaced it with MB1 and doing Ctrl-Z is not a solution ?
- How do I align vertices to the grid but only using the axis of my choice ?  (ex: align on the X axis grid or any other axis of my choice)
- how do I group object parts (vertices, faces, ...) as different groups and then working with the group of my choice ?
- how can I maximize the view port with one single keys shortcut thus hiding every menus and then once I am done doing what I wanted to on that maxed view, revert back to whatever interface view I was using before ?
- how to select anything using a region drawn by mouse movements (meaning selecting without using box or circle or shift, just mouse mouvements)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly blender 2.80 is under heavy development while making some major changes so can be of varying functionality for now. I would suggest you start learning with 2.79b until 2.80 is finished.

There are several options when it comes to choosing a [pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html), I think what you are referring to is setting the [object origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/origin.html).

There are several [snapping options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) and ways to [control transformations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/index.html). You can limit movement to one axis by pressing it's key while transforming, eg <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> will only move along the X axis, you can not move on one axis by adding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> - <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> will move on Y and Z but not X. To align vertices to one axis is it common to scale to zero one the axis, eg <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> will scale the verts on the x axis so they all align, in object mode you can do the same as long as you enable [manipulate centre points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/manipulate_center_points.html). There are align options available in some addons, like [align tools](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Align_Tools) and [mesh align plus](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Mesh_Align_Plus).

Blender doesn't have vertex grouping and I don't know of any addons that add it. You can assign vertices to a [vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) and use that to select/deselect a collection of vertices.

There are two options to [maximise the viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html#toggle-maximize-area) - <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑ Up arrow</kbd> will maximize the viewport, the info bar at the top and headers for the view will remain in place or <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> will make the view full screen also removing the info bar and headers. Also the window layouts are saved as [screens](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/screens.html) which you can make and define to your liking, by saving these screens in your [startup blend](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/startup_file.html) you can keep them available each time you use blender. The default screens include a 3D only layout.

For [lasso select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/tools.html#lasso-select) you can hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while pressing the non-select mouse button to draw an arbitrary region to select items within.